fastapi returns HTML on HTTPException
I'm trying to return a HTML response on HTTPException for a display board, so it can reload on connection errors:
from fastapi import HTTPException
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse, JSONResponse

class ReloadException(HTTPException):
  """ return a HTMLResponse so browser will try reload later """
  def __init__(self, status_code:int=500, detail:str=None):
    self.status_code = status_code
    self.detail = detail

    self.resp = HTMLResponse(
      status_code=self.status_code,
      content=f"<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"60\"></head><body>error:{self.detail}</body></html>",
      headers={'Content-Type': 'text/html'}
    )

    # self.resp = JSONResponse(json.dumps({"detail": self.detail}), status_code=self.status_code)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.resp
:
# connection test
try:
  r = await s.get(url, headers={'PRIVATE-TOKEN': config.get_config()['gitlabtoken']})
  r.raise_for_status()
except httpx.HTTPError as exc:
  raise ReloadException(status_code=500, detail=f"{exc.request.url} - {exc}")
    if r and r.status_code!=200:
      raise HTTPException(status_code=r.status_code, detail=f"{r.text}")

I get this error from starlette:
  File "site-packages\starlette\responses.py", line 49, in render
    return content.encode(self.charset)  # type: ignore
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'encode'

UPDATED
Sending content as string (as suggested by @MatsLindh corrected above), but it still returns json.
curl.exe -v "http://localhost:8000/lastjobs"
*   Trying [::1]:8000...
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8000...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8000
> GET /lastjobs HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8000
> User-Agent: curl/8.4.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< date: Wed, 03 Apr 2024 13:20:43 GMT
< server: uvicorn
< content-length: 100
< content-type: application/json
<
{"detail":"https://xxxxxxx/api/v4/projects/2309 - [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed"}


content should be just the string, not a dict with message: content=f"<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"60\"></head><body>error:{self.detail}</body></html>": https://www.starlette.io/responses/#response

try "Content-Type": "appliation/json" or sending content as string not json
